# Book identification: captain of a trade ship travels with sentient feline

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for the author or title of a book I read about 40 years ago. The captain of space faring trade ship travels with a sentient feline being who can speak. I believe there was another alien on board also.
They would fight, scheme and get into situations in their travels.
Thanks, 
maravill

Comment: Can you remember other details?

Comment: Does honor Harrington ring a bell? I think in one of the later books in the series she was on a trade ship, and she's always got her empathic treecat.

Comment: @Gus - The Harrington novels were only started in 1992, so reading them 40 years ago would be a bit tricky...

Answer (score 6):

Not much to go on but this sounds like one of Poul Anderson's *[David Falkayn](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?21005)* stories.
Perhaps *Trader to the Stars* or *Satan's World*.

David Falkayn has two companions. Chee Lan is a catlike alien and Adzel is described as dragonlike.

See [Baen Books](https://www.baen.com/Chapters/141655520X/141655520X.htm?blurb) which has *The Trouble Twisters* (part of *Trader to the Stars*)

> Besides Falkayn, there's Chee Lan, a tempestuous felinesque being,
> considerably smaller than a human but with enough attitude for a whole
> battalion of monkey-boys (or girls), covered with silky-white fur, and
> a crack shot with a blaster. Better not beat her at poker—or do
> anything else to get her mad. But she keeps a cool head in a crisis:
> "glacially self-possessed," as Poul Anderson puts it. Then there's
> Adzel, as imperturbable as Chee Lan is high-strung, and I suspect that
> his imperturbability has less to do with his being a Buddhist than
> with his reptilian species' having evolved on a planet where they're
> the biggest life form—not quite elephant sized. They are dragonlike,
> but also centaurlike, with four legs and an additional two arms. He
> abhors violence, but has no problem with self-defense—or defense of
> his comrades.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Fruitbat. I don't know why I just got notice of your answer but you are correct. Yaaaay!